# Filter the loaded data using ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I first preload the activerecord another with one-to-many active records. 
Is it possible to filter out the data like the followings without querying the database again?

```
animal = @Animals.all.includes({:cats})
animal.where([:cat_category=>"home_cat"]) ### This one
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is located inside a method, for example

```
def load_something
  animal = @Animals.all.load([:cats])
  animal.where([:cat_category=>"home_cat"]) ### This one
end
```

Rails is smart enough to make only 1 request to DB.
If you check this in `rails console`, one line, then type other, it will make 2 requests, but in app, rails will amke from this only 1 DB request